# mapping English words to their singular forms

Tags: nlp

Examples:
mapping a plural noun to its singular form:  children --> child, boxes ---> box
mapping comparative and superlative of adjectives and adverbs to their basic form
mapping verb ....

I once found an open source resource to achieve it. As I remember, it is a datasheet?/spreadsheet?/database? of the mapping. Does anyone know the open source resource, or any alternative/better solution?
I'm coding in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called *stemming* and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (specifically [snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) contrib) can do that.

There is a number of [different stemming algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068790/difference-between-lucene-stemmers-englishstemmer-porterstemmer-lovinsstemmer).

Comment: Actually the process is called lemmatization. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4025259/547040).

Comment: @Khairul Interesting. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming#Lemmatisation_algorithms) that lemmatisation is the subset of stemming.

Answer (score 0):

There was a paper in the '80s about the UNIX spell checker which explained how stemming worked. This [Wikipedia UNIX Spell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_%28Unix%29) article gives a link to the paper, and also identifies some alternatives.